# On open, Rstudio starts many processes (started with parallel package in previous session) -- how to kill them?

Tags: r, rstudio, parallel-foreach, doparallel

I have read through this SO question and answers ([R parallel computing and zombie processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388139/r-parallel-computing-and-zombie-processes)) but it doesn't seem to quite address my situation.

I have a 4-core MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.10.3, R 3.2.0, and RStudio 0.99.441.

Yesterday, I was trying out the packages "foreach" and "doParallel" (I want to use them in a package I am working on).  I did this:

```
cl <- makeCluster(14)
registerDoParallel(cl)

a <- 0
ls <- foreach(icount(100)) %dopar% {
    b <- a + 1
}
```

It is clear to me that it doesn't make sense to have 14 processes on my 4-core machine, but the software will actually be run on a 16-core machine.  At this point my computer ground to a halt.  I opened activity monitor and found 16 (or more, maybe?) R processes.  I tried to force quit them from the activity monitor -- no luck.  I closed RStudio and that killed all the R processes.  I reopened RStudio and that restarted all the R processes.  I restarted the computer and restarted RStudio and that restarted all the R processes.

How can I start RStudio without restarting all those processes?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I also rebuilt the package I was working on at the time (all the processes may have been running during the build)

EDIT2:  Also, I can't StopCluster(cl) because cl is not in the environment anymore...I closed that R session.

EDIT3:  When I open R.app (The R GUI provided with R) or open R in the terminal, no such problem occurs.  So I think it must be RStudio-related.

EDIT4:  There appears to be a random delay between opening RStudio and the starting of all these undesired processes.  Between 15s and 2 mins.

EDIT5:  It seems the processes only start after I open the project from which they were started.

EDIT6:  I have been picking through the .Rproj.user files looking for things to delete.  I deleted all the files (but not the directories) in ctx, pcs, and sdb.  Problem persists.

EDIT7:  When I run "killall R" at the command line it kills all these processes, but when I restart RStudio and reopen the project, all the processes start again.

EDIT8:  I used "killall -s R | wc -l" to find that the number of R processes grows and grows while the project is open.  It got up to 358 and then I ran "killall R" because my computer was making scary sounds.

EDIT9:  RStudio is completely unusable currently.  Every time I "killall R", it restarts all the processes within 15 seconds.

EDIT10:  When I initiate a build that also starts up tons of R processes -- 109 at last check.  These processes all get started up when the build says "preparing package  for lazy loading".  At this point the computer grinds to a near-halt.

EDIT11:  I deleted the .Rproj file (actually just moved it as a backup) and the .Rproj.user directory.  I used "create project from directory" in RStudio.  When I open that NEW project, I still get the same behavior.  What is RStudio doing when I open a project that isn't contained anywhere in the .Rproj file or the .Rproj.user directory!?  I've spent the whole day on this one problem....:(

Comment: See here for resetting rstudio to a fresh state: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-s-State

Comment: Jay, thanks for your suggestion.  I did what was described on that page and it definitely reset my RStudio settings (layout, appearance, etc.), but when I start RStudio, it still starts all the unwanted processes.

Comment: And I'll just add -- I think your suggestion could be an answer (rather than a comment).  Just because it's easy/short doesn't mean it couldn't have been the completely correct and most useful response!

Comment: I have just run this on my macbook pro with `makeCluster(32)` and (i) my computer did not freeze (in fact the code finished pretty much instantaneously) and (ii) after restarting RStudio the R processes did not reappear.

Comment: @Roland, maybe it has something to do with building the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up fixing it:

Delete the package I built (the binary, I believe...I clicked the "x" to the right of it's name in the "Packages" part of RStudio).

Rebuild it, with

```
library(parallel)
```

commented out.

Comment: Why do you have a `library` call in your package? State dependencies in your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Totally fair point.  As described in the original question, I was just playing around with the parallel package to see how it worked.  I had a file called "temp.R" where I was doing some "hello world" type stuff.  Live and learn.  Maybe the trick is to call that file "temp.txt" or anything other than ".R" so that, should I want to rebuild while the file exists, it gets ignored.

OR, just add that file to .buildignore!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess -- the newest version of RStudio tries to do some work behind the scenes to develop an autocompletion database, based on `library()` and `require()` calls it detects within open files in your project. To do this, it launches new R processes, loads those packages (with `library()`), and then returns the set of all objects made available by that package.

By any chance are you loading certain packages that have complex `.onLoad()` actions? It's possible that this engine in RStudio is running those in R processes behind the scenes, but getting stuck for some reason and leaving you with these (maybe stale or busy) R processes.

For reference, there was somewhat similar issue reported [here](https://github.com/ropensci/ecoretriever/issues/49).

Comment: Kevin -- thanks for the insight.  I bet it is something along these lines.  But the package I'm working on has lots of dependencies, so maybe the best solution is just to go back to a previous version of RStudio?  I do love the code completion in the new RStudio, though.

Comment: If you happen to narrow down the problem, please submit a bug report at http://support.rstudio.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
unloadNamespace("doParallel")
```

will kill the unnamed worker started by `registerDoParallel`

if you have the name of the clusters, you can use:

```
stopCluster(cl)
```